# I have a string and i need to extract some value from it and put that value into another string in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to fetch the value of **hobby** i.e **cricket** from the string, any idea how to do that

```
  String str = "welcome to stackoverflow :
                  person_name : abc
                  hobby : cricket
                  Class : xyz "
```

i know the concept of substring but how to set the index value.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also `String.indexOf`

Comment: [Java: method to get position of a match in a String?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2615749)

Comment: can you please illustrate the output that i want with code.

Comment: you can also use regex expression

Comment: explain with the help of code

Comment: You asked [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230399/i-have-a-string-and-i-need-to-fetch-some-value-from-it-and-put-that-value-into-a) 3 hours ago which was closed due to lack of information. Do you think asking the exact same again will help?

Answer (score 1):

Given that your string has always the same format. We need to find the indexes of `hobby` and `Class` via `String.indexOf(String)`:

```
String findHobbyInString(String str) {
int idxBegin = str.indexOf("hobby : ");
if (idxBegin < 0) {
  return null;
}
int idxEnd = str.indexOf("Class : ");
if (idxEnd < 0) {
  return str.substring(idxBegin + 8).trim();
}
return str.substring(idxBegin + 8, idxEnd).trim();
}
```

And also, because there is so much white space, I use `trim()` to remove this.